# How to create a Progress Bar in R (or Python) using a heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap

i'd like to recreate chart in link below, in R or Python.
I do have the code to create de colorful bar, with ggplplot2 and geom_tiles, with color gradient.
I have no idea how to include the Faded color in background. Plot is from Grafana, I like the design and i was wondering if i could reproduce it in R.

[Progress Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2AGv.png)

So far I can create this, without color scale like image.
Any advice would be appreciated

```
# Crear los dataframes
dx1 <- data.frame(hour = 1:100, value = rep(1, 100))
dx2 <- data.frame(hour = 101:200, value = rep(1, 200))

# Crear el heatmap
ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data = dx1, aes(x = hour, y = 1, fill = "red"), color = "grey", alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_tile(data = dx2, aes(x = hour, y = 1, fill = "red"), color = "grey", alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 24, by = 3)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red")) +
  xlab("Hour of day") +
  ylab("") +
  ggtitle("Heatmap with one row") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "right")
```